# Trying to concatenate the last 10 lines of a log file to a batch variable using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, logging, scripting

I'm new to Windows scripting, but have quite a lot of experience in bash and python.

Here's the issue. Whenever I run this, (and this is the best result I've gotten so far) it makes it most of the way through and then errors with "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Ignore the code designed for newlines, I'm still fighting with that as well.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set LAST_TEN=Here are the last 10 lines of the download log:
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%x in (`powershell -command "& {Get-Content download.log | Select-Object -last 10 | ForEach-Object {$_.substring(2)}}"`) do (
    
    set LAST_TEN=!LAST_TEN!%%x
    
    
)

echo %LAST_TEN%
```

The reason I'm taking the substring is because some of the lines in the logfile start with < and > . I thought that was my only issue, but that is not the case. Please let me know if any more info is needed. Thank you!

Comment: You need to protect the special characters within the set command. `set "LAST_TEN=!LAST_TEN!%%x"`

Comment: No luck, same exact error

Comment: why on _EARTH_ are you mixing BAT/CMD with PoSh? you can do all that you show in powershell ... so why mix the two?

Comment: This is only a small snippet of my full script, the rest of which functions as intended. I'm sure I could rewrite the whole thing in powershell, but as I said, I've never actually used it before. I've been running linux since I got into tech. Considering the time I've already sunk into the project, I'm hoping there's a solution that works in batch.

Comment: And what line of code is executing when you receive that error?

Comment: The last line. It actually seems to correctly add all 10 lines from the logfile that I want to the variable, it just also adds that error on the end, which seems to be in reference to a combination of my current working directory, and a directory in the logfile I'm reading.

Comment: Did you try `echo !last_ten!`?

Comment: As an aside: `Get-Content download.log -Tail 10` will do - no need for a separate `Select-Object` call - and perform much better. Also, there's no reason to use `& { ... }` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `...` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: Your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69905327/45375) shows the effective solution, but I thought I'd provide some background information.</sup>

[Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) has provided the crucial pointer:

- Switching from `echo %LAST_TEN%` to `echo !LAST_TEN!` avoids problems with metacharacters (special characters such as `<` and `>`) in the variable *value*, which are what caused your error message.
- The alternative would be to *double-quote* the variable reference - `echo "%LAST_TEN%"` - but, sadly, the double quotes are then *included in the output*.

In other words: **If you need to `echo` the value of a variable that (potentially) contains metacharacters *unquoted***:

- Place **`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`** at the start of your batch file.
- Then **reference the variable of interest as `!VAR!`** instead of `%VAR%`: the ***delayed* expansion** this results in prevents the value from becoming *part of the source-code line that `cmd.exe` parses* (due to the macro-style up-front expansion that happens with `%VAR%`).

  - As an aside: *Loop* variables - such as `%%x` in your code - despite using `%` rather than `!` as the delimiter, are of necessity *always* expanded in a *delayed* fashion, which is the reason that `set LAST_TEN=!LAST_TEN!%%x` worked even *without* the double-quoting around enclosing both the variable name and value that is normally required for literals and values of *non*-delayed variable references containing metacharacters (e.g.
    `set "LAST_TEN=a < b"`)

A simplified example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define a sample variable
:: Note the "..." enclosing both the name and the value.
set "var=a value with metacharacters: < > & |"

:: Thanks to using !var!, echoing the value *unquoted* works
echo !var!
```

***Scoping* `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`**:

One pitfall of delayed expansion is that that *all* `!` characters are then considered part of delayed variable references, typically resulting in their *quiet removal*; e.g., `echo hi!` outputs just `hi`.
To *escape* `!` characters in *literal* strings that should be used verbatim, you need `^^!` (sic) in *unquoted* strings, and `^!` inside `"..."`.

The escaping is also needed for `%...%` variable references (e.g., `echo %var:!=^^!%`), but is again avoided for `!...!` ones.

To avoid such escaping headaches you can enable `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` *on demand*, for a given line or block of lines, and disable it again with `endlocal`:

```
@echo off

:: Define a sample variable
:: Note the "..." enclosing both the name and the value.
set "var=a value with metacharacters: < > & |"

:: Because setlocal enableDelayedExpansion is NOT (yet)
:: in effect, the use of "!" is not a problem.
echo hi!

:: Localize the use of delayed expansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo !var!
endlocal

:: Use of "!" is again fine.
echo hi again!
```

**Caveat**: Since `setlocal` creates a *copy* of the environment variables, which `endlocal` then *discards*, do not try to *set* variables between `setlocal` and `endlocal` if you need later code to see these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

`echo %LAST_TEN%`

to

`echo !LAST_TEN!`

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using PowerShell, why not let it do the donkey work?

Grab the last ten lines and concatenate them within parentheses, for example:

```sh
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content 'download.log' | Select-Object -Last 10) -Join ''"') Do Set "LAST_TEN=%%G"
```